# Importing Jar files for JReddit giving error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, reddit, jreddit

I get Errors when trying to import the jar files needed for Jreddit to function.

On jreddit's github page it says  ...

> Dependencies
>
> JSON-simple
>
> Apache HttpComponents
>
> Apache Commons IO

After going to the Maven repository website I download the jar files from the following links ..

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io

and importing them to my intellij project I simply

⌘ + ; on Mac OS X → Module → Dependencies → Add... → Project Library → Attach Jar

I get the following errors...
[image: Error messages when importing jar files into the my java project]

Error message is : Cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: It looks like jars doesn't contain this class or you add it for wrong module.
Why don't create maven project and add all this dependencies in pom.xml?

Comment: Ive never done one before , any tutorials you recommend?

Comment: Maven: 
http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-tutorial.html
IDEA maven: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/maven-projects-tool-window.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm the current mantainer for jReddit.

First of all, I think you are using an old version of jReddit. From the looks of it you are using `1.0.0` which is the first version. Current version is `1.0.2`. Try downloading the jar from [here](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.jreddit%7Cjreddit%7C1.0.2%7Cjar).

Secondly, my recommendation is to include the dependency using maven rather through importing the jar manually.

I've created for you a small pom.xml how to create a simple maven project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.yourcompany.test</groupId>
<artifactId>jreddit-testing</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>jreddit-testing</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jreddit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jreddit</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Try to add your source code in `src/main/java`

After you finish, run from the command line `mvn clean install` (keep in mind you need maven installed locally, although AFAIK intellij comes with an embedded maven).

For more about maven, check out [this guy](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials/)

Comment: Hey , Thank you for the answer , Im running into a little problem  , after running mvn clean install , it downloads the packages fine , but then when i run the program i get the error 
Error:java: directory not found: /Users/"myname"/Documents/workspace/jredditTesting/target/generated-sources/annotations

Comment: after changing from intellij to eclipse i got it to work , now I'm wondering how can I retrieve top 10 comments for for a submission of the world news subreddit?